Ошибка WebSocket connection failed
Пытаюсь настроить WebSocket.
var chat = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/ws/');

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://site.com:8082/"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://site.com:8082/"

</VirtualHost>

Когда был установлен только apache все работало хорошо. Теперь вместе с apache установлен и nginx. Прописываю в конфиге nginx код:
    location /ws {
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass        http://site.com:8082/ws;
    }      

Получаю ошибку "WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com/ws/' failed"
Вопрос. что я делаю не так?
